# Get notified if started process exited

Tags: c#, wpf

I am Running a WPF application (process A). From this on a button click I need to start another process (process B), which is a WinForms application.

Now my question is if I close process B's window by clicking the (X)-button, which closes process B abruptly then how to notify this event info to process A?

Answer (score 1):

if you are executing your external application using `Process.Start` then you can use `WaitForExit` method that will hold your cursor until the application is not exited. Take a look at this example to understand more about WaitForExit method on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The Process class has an [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event for exactly this purpose. You also have to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `true` to use it:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Exited += ProcessExited;
    process.Start();

    startButton.IsEnabled = false;
}

private void ProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => startButton.IsEnabled = true));
}
```

Comment: Hi @Clemens,Thank you Very much for your answer... I already tried this Event but after Process exit it is not coming to Event routine to execute, means it is not raising that event.... Can you give me any other way to do so....

Comment: There are two possible reasons why this might happen. Either you did not properly register your `Exited` handler, including setting `EnableRaisingEvents` to true, or the process does not actually terminate, but only closes its main window. Did you check (e.g. with Task Manager) if it really exits or if it is perhaps still running?